# apache bad request with 443 and reverse proxy

Tags: docker, apache, apache2

I have 2 docker containers, 1 running apache2 and 1 running a python api.
In non-https, I was able to make the connection such that requests on 80 are channeled to the docker container running the python api. When I enable HTTPS, requests come in as 400 (bad request).
Any help greatly appreciated. This is my virtual host file.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName domain.com

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://172.17.0.1:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://172.17.0.1:8000/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/usr/local/apache2/conf/.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/usr/local/apache2/conf/.key"

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache logs should contain a more detailed error, however based on the configuration you posted, I would check if  "/usr/local/apache2/conf/.crt" and "/usr/local/apache2/conf/.key" exists.